Develop a more robust method to handle words that don’t affect the similarity ratio when reconstructing sentences using fuzz.ratio?
I'm working on a project where I'm reconstructing sentences extracted from a PDF. The sentences are preprocessed using sent_tokenize from nltk, while the words I’m trying to match are extracted directly from the original PDF (non-preprocessed). Due to these differences, I’m using fuzz.ratio from the fuzzywuzzy (or thefuzz) library to compare and reconstruct sentences as closely as possible, allowing for slight variations such as punctuation, spacing, or line breaks.
The problem I'm encountering is that certain words don’t affect the similarity ratio when added, meaning they get added to the current sentence when they might actually belong to the next one. In one case, this even happened with a word like "Following," which I would have expected to be quite substantial.
Additionally, sentence length seems to impact this: as the sentence grows, the effect of adding individual words diminishes, making it harder to decide where they belong. I’ve also tried checking these words in the following sentence, but this introduces further complexity:

The word might exist in both sentences, leading to a character match that falsely increases the ratio.
The partial match of the word’s characters in the following sentence might make it seem like the word belongs there when it doesn’t.

Why I'm Using fuzz.ratio:
The sentences I'm reconstructing have been preprocessed with nltk's sent_tokenize, so they may differ from the extracted words (which are pulled from the raw, unprocessed document). fuzz.ratio allows for these differences, handling minor discrepancies in punctuation and spacing.
Minimal example where I'm trying to construct a sentence from a subset of the extracted words:
from thefuzz import fuzz

# List of words extracted from a PDF (subset example)
all_pages_words = [
    {"word": "Following"}, {"word": "the"}, {"word": "guidelines"}, 
    {"word": "for"}, {"word": "submission"}, {"word": "are"}, {"word": "critical"},
    {"word": "to"}, {"word": "success"}
]

# Sentence to match against
sentence_token = "Following the guidelines for submission"

# Construct sentence and calculate similarity
constructed_sentence = ""
old_similarity_ratio = fuzz.ratio(sentence_token, constructed_sentence)
starting_index = 0

while starting_index < len(all_pages_words):
    last_word_index_pre_concatenation = len(constructed_sentence)
    constructed_sentence += " " + all_pages_words[starting_index]["word"]
    
    new_similarity_ratio = fuzz.ratio(sentence_token, constructed_sentence)
    
    # Problem: some words don't affect the similarity ratio, causing issues
    if new_similarity_ratio < old_similarity_ratio:
        # Roll back and stop
        constructed_sentence = constructed_sentence[:last_word_index_pre_concatenation]
        break
    else:
        old_similarity_ratio = new_similarity_ratio
    
    starting_index += 1

print(f"Final constructed sentence: {constructed_sentence.strip()}")

When reconstructing long sentences, adding individual words (especially toward the end) doesn't significantly change the ratio, making it hard to determine if they belong.
I’ve tried checking if these words belong to the following sentence, but this leads to new problems:

The word might exist in both sentences, leading to partial character matches and falsely increasing the ratio.
As the next sentence grows, the buffered word’s effect becomes smaller, making it hard to determine if it truly belongs.

I even tried to develop a system where I construct the sentence twice, once from each direction (left-right and right-left) to ensure the ratio changes stay significant, but this is also not entirely robust and adds more complexity (not sure if I am overcomplicating this)
Question

How can I create a more robust method to handle these words that don’t significantly affect the similarity ratio when reconstructing sentences?
Are there better ways to check where these words belong without falsely attributing them to the wrong sentence?

